# Federal treatment of recaptured depreciation paid to DC?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, real-estate, tax-deduction

Can I deduct from 2014 federal taxes the amount of recaptured depreciation paid to DC for 2013 on the sale of a property that was part rental/part principal residence?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to deduct recaptured depreciation that's already been taxed and paid in 2013 on a 2014 return?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deduct state income taxes paid, in the year you paid them, if you itemize your deductions on Schedule A of your Federal tax return.

This is deduction from *income*, not a tax credit.